# Development for smaller screens

Tags: ios, uikit

We are developing application in Xcode 6 with deployment target of iOS 7. I was wondering what is best practice or how do we define that some UIViews should have different height on 3.5 and 4 inch screens? Our designer made graphic design of the application in photoshop for iPhone 6/6+, but it doesn't fit vertically well on smaller screens, so we can make everything a bit smaller, but the question what is the best practice doing this in code and/or in storyboard.

BTW: I am used to do everything in code as I don't like working with IB

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is learn how to use AutoLayout to make constraints that adjust according to the screen size. This takes a lot of trial and error, playing with priorities etc. and if things change in a view you often have to fix a lot of constraints to get it working again. You could also build views and/or constraints in code, but I don't have much experience with that.

Alternatively you can make different storyboards for different screen sizes, but then you'd have to manage the two different versions.

Comment: I need to work this out in code if possible.